# How to disable "Error message in Apex Oracle"

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX, when a form field is required, an error message appears below the relevant field. However, there is also an error message displayed in orange. Is there a way to remove this message?

I've asked to other developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a native way, it is not achievable. However, you can set a CSS rule on your page to hide the error alert field by putting the following in the page's inline css section:

```
#t_Alert_Notification{display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It wooooorks !